# Get items from specific template from sitecore content tree in JSS

Tags: jss

I am creating a left navigation component in sitecoreJSS (using Angular), for this I need to retrieve complete tree under specific node, and I created a left navigation template and inherited this template to existing template that I want to use items from particular templates.

I want to retrieve all the items created from these templates.

Comment: You should make use of a graphql query

Answer (score 1):

You have to use graphQL to fetch any item which is not a datasource item or context item in JSS.

But with the default setup you can use graphQL to do the same, sample query to fetch all the folder items under "Home"

```
query RetrieveContentItems($itemPath: String = "/sitecore/content/Home") {

  rootItem: item(path: $itemPath)
  {
    children(includeTemplateIDs: "{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}")
    {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new template(optional) with a field as multilist, set the datasource to a specific location(home node) and add condition for your template.
Now you can use this field as your left navigation, where you can get title/links and other fields(if required).